# Second insert statement not inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two insert statement in my SQL query. however it insert the data for first statement only. it does not inserting Data for second insert statement.

```
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[prAddUpdateOrderDetails]    Script Date: 4/10/2019 12:49:24 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
Name                :   [prAddUpdateOrderDetails]
Parameters          :       
Descripton          :   This sp is to add and update Orders
Author              :   Saion Corp.
Sample Exec         :   DECLARE @p1 INT
                        DECLARE @p2 [dbo].[udtOrderDetails]
                            INSERT INTO @p2 VALUES(0,0,7,0,2,1,200.00,200.00,200.00,20.00,220.00,240.00,12,'01/01/2000','01/01/2000',200.00,0)
                        DECLARE @p3 [dbo].[udtOrderProductAttributes]
                            INSERT INTO @p3 VALUES(0,0,7,5,1,'Sites','5 Users',1,1,10,1,0,0,10)
                        DECLARE @p4 [dbo].[udtOrderPromotions]
                            INSERT INTO @p4 VALUES(0,0,7,5,1,'Sites','5 Users',1,1,10,1,0,0,10)
                        DECLARE @p5 [dbo].[udtOrderDetailPromotions]
                            INSERT INTO @p5 VALUES(0,0,7,5,1,'Sites','5 Users',1,1,10,1,0,0,10)
                        EXEC [prAddUpdateOrderDetails]  @OrderID = 0                                                        
                                                        ,@SegmentId = 2
                                                        ,@OrganizationId INT
                                                        ,@CreatedBy = 1
                                                        ,@OrderNumber = ''
                                                        ,@Amount = 24.0
                                                        ,@AMB = true
                                                        ,@TotalAmount = 36.00
                                                        ,@AdditionalSalesReps = ''
                                                        ,@AdditionalNotes = ''
                                                        ,@PromotionAmt =45.00
                                                        ,@Subscription = 'JSON'
                                                        ,@OrderPhaseId = 1
                                                        ,@OrderDetails = @p2
                                                        ,@OrderProductAttributes = @p3
                                                        ,@OrderPromotions = @p4
                                                        ,@OrderDetailPromotions = @p5
                                                        ,@NewOrderId = @p1 OUTPUT
                                                    SELECT @p1

Modified History    :
*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prAddUpdateOrderDetails] @OrderID INT
    ,@BillTo VARCHAR(20)
    ,@ShipTo VARCHAR(20)
    ,@SegmentId INT
    ,@OrganizationId INT
    ,@CreatedBy INT
    ,@OrderNumber NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@CustomerName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@Email NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@ContactNumber NVARCHAR(30)
    ,@Amount DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,@AMB BIT
    ,@TotalAmount DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,@AdditionalSalesReps NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@AdditionalNotes NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@PromotionAmt DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,@Subscription NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@OrderPhaseId INT
    ,@OrderDetails udtOrderDetails READONLY
    ,@OrderProductAttributes udtOrderProductAttributes READONLY
    ,@OrderPromotions udtOrderPromotions READONLY
    ,@OrderDetailPromotions udtOrderDetailPromotions READONLY
    ,@NewOrderId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ErrSeverity INT
DECLARE @Quantity INT
DECLARE @ProductId INT
DECLARE @ParentProductId INT
DECLARE @WeightedAmount DECIMAL(18, 2)
DECLARE @AttributeId INT
DECLARE @AttributeName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CustomerEntersQty BIT
DECLARE @AttributeQuantity INT
DECLARE @TotalRecords INT
DECLARE @CurrentRow INT
DECLARE @TempOrderDetails TABLE (
    OrderId INT
    ,OrderDetailId INT
    ,ProductID INT
    )

BEGIN TRANSACTION ShopCT_TRAN;

BEGIN TRY
    -- Insert into Orders table
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].[Orders]
            WHERE OrderId = @OrderID
            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] (
            [BillTo]
            ,[ShipTo]
            ,[SegmentId]
            ,[OrganizationId]
            ,[CreatedBy]
            ,[OrderNumber]
            ,[CustomerName]
            ,[Email]
            ,[ContactNumber]
            ,[Amount]
            ,[TotalAmount]
            ,[AdditionalSalesReps]
            ,[AdditionalNotes]
            --,[OrderDate]
            ,[PromotionAmt]
            ,[Subscription]
            ,[OrderPhaseId]
            ,[AMB]
            )
        VALUES (
            @BillTo
            ,@ShipTo
            ,@SegmentId
            ,@OrganizationId
            ,@CreatedBy
            ,@OrderNumber
            ,@CustomerName
            ,@Email
            ,@ContactNumber
            ,@Amount
            ,@TotalAmount
            ,@AdditionalSalesReps
            ,@AdditionalNotes
            --,GETDATE()
            ,@PromotionAmt
            ,@Subscription
            ,@OrderPhaseId
            ,@AMB
            );

        SET @OrderId = CONVERT(INT, SCOPE_IDENTITY());

        DECLARE @OPhaseId INT = (
                SELECT OrderPhaseId
                FROM OrderPhase
                WHERE OrderPhase = 'Shopping Carts'
                );

        -- Order Processings entry when order created or shopping cart
        INSERT INTO OrderProcessings (
            [OrderId]
            ,[OrderPhase_Id]
            ,[CreatedBy]
            )
        VALUES (
            @OrderID
            ,@OPhaseId
            ,@CreatedBy
            )

        SELECT @NewOrderId = @OrderId;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (
                @OrderNumber IS NOT NULL
                AND @OrderNumber <> ''
                )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[Orders]
            SET OrderDate = GETDATE()
            WHERE OrderId = @OrderID
                AND OrderDate IS NULL
        END

        UPDATE [dbo].[Orders]
        SET [CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy
            ,[OrderNumber] = @OrderNumber
            ,[Amount] = @Amount
            ,[TotalAmount] = @TotalAmount
            ,[AdditionalSalesReps] = @AdditionalSalesReps
            ,[AdditionalNotes] = @AdditionalNotes
            ,[PromotionAmt] = @PromotionAmt
            ,[Subscription] = @Subscription
            ,[OrderPhaseId] = @OrderPhaseId
            ,[AMB] = @AMB
            ,[UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
        WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
            AND BillTo = @BillTo
            AND ShipTo = @ShipTo;

        SELECT @NewOrderId = @OrderId;
    END

    --Deleting from OrderPromotion
    DELETE
    FROM [dbo].[OrderPromotions]
    WHERE [OrderId] = @OrderID;-- Removing exist Order Promotion for current order  

    --Deleting from OrderDetailsPromotion                   
    DELETE
    FROM OrderDetailPromotions
    WHERE OrderDetailId IN (
            SELECT OrderDetailId
            FROM @OrderDetails
            );-- Removing exist Order Promotion for current order
        --Deleting from OrderProductAttributes

    DELETE
    FROM [dbo].OrderProductAttributes
    WHERE OrderDetailId IN (
            SELECT OrderDetailId
            FROM @OrderDetails
            WHERE UpdateType = 2
            )
        AND OrderProductAttributes.OrderId = @OrderID;

    --Deleting from OrderProcessings
    DELETE
    FROM [dbo].[OrderProcessings]
    WHERE [OrderId] = @OrderID;

    --Deleting from OrderDetails 
    DELETE
    FROM [dbo].OrderDetails
    WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT OrderDetailId
            FROM @OrderDetails
            WHERE UpdateType = 2
            )
        AND OrderDetails.OrderId = @OrderID;

    --Insert Into OrderDetails
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderDetails] (
        [OrderId]
        ,[ProductId]
        ,[ParentProductId]
        ,[SegmentId]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[Price]
        ,[SubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[OneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionSubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionOneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[TotalPrice]
        ,[SubscriptionTerm]
        ,[SubscriptionStartDate]
        ,[SubscriptionEndDate]
        ,[SubscriptionTotal]
        ,[Subscription]
        ,[CreatedBy]
        )
    SELECT @OrderID
        ,[ProductId]
        ,[ParentProductId]
        ,[SegmentId]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[Price]
        ,[SubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[OneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionSubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionOneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[TotalPrice]
        ,[SubscriptionTerm]
        ,[SubscriptionStartDate]
        ,[SubscriptionEndDate]
        ,[SubscriptionTotal]
        ,[Subscription]
        ,@CreatedBy
    FROM @OrderDetails
    WHERE OrderDetailId = 0
        AND UpdateType = 0;

    --Inserting New Order Details ID in @TempOrderDetails
    INSERT INTO @TempOrderDetails (
        OrderId
        ,OrderDetailId
        ,ProductID
        )
    SELECT A.OrderId
        ,A.ID
        ,A.ProductId
    FROM OrderDetails A
    INNER JOIN @OrderDetails B ON A.ProductId = B.ProductID
        AND A.OrderId = @OrderId
    WHERE B.OrderDetailId = 0
        AND B.UpdateType = 0;

    --Updating OrderDetails
    UPDATE [dbo].[OrderDetails]
    SET [OrderId] = A.OrderId
        ,[ProductId] = A.ProductId
        ,[ParentProductId] = A.ParentProductId
        ,[SegmentId] = A.SegmentId
        ,[Quantity] = A.Quantity
        ,[Price] = A.Price
        ,[SubscriptionAttributePrice] = A.[SubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[OneTimeAttributePrice] = A.[OneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionSubscriptionAttributePrice] = A.[PromotionSubscriptionAttributePrice]
        ,[PromotionOneTimeAttributePrice] = A.[PromotionOneTimeAttributePrice]
        ,[TotalPrice] = A.TotalPrice
        ,[SubscriptionTerm] = A.SubscriptionTerm
        ,[SubscriptionStartDate] = A.SubscriptionStartDate
        ,[SubscriptionEndDate] = A.SubscriptionEndDate
        ,[SubscriptionTotal] = A.SubscriptionTotal
        ,[Subscription] = A.Subscription
        ,[UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
    FROM @OrderDetails A
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails B ON A.OrderDetailId = B.Id
    WHERE B.OrderId = @OrderID
        AND A.UpdateType = 1;

    --Insert Into [dbo].[OrderProductAttributes]
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderProductAttributes] (
        [OrderId]
        ,[OrderDetailId]
        ,[ProductId]
        ,[AttributeId]
        ,[Product_ProductAttribute_MappingId]
        ,[ProductAttributeValueId]
        ,[AttributeType]
        ,[AttributeName]
        ,[Name]
        ,[IsSubscription]
        ,[PriceAdjustment]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[CustomerEntersQty]
        ,[TotalPriceAdjustment]
        ,CreatedBy
        )
    SELECT B.OrderId
        ,B.OrderDetailId
        ,A.ProductId
        ,A.AttributeId
        ,A.Product_ProductAttribute_MappingId
        ,A.ProductAttributeValueId
        ,A.AttributeType
        ,A.AttributeName
        ,A.Name
        ,A.IsSubscription
        ,A.PriceAdjustment
        ,A.Quantity
        ,A.CustomerEntersQty
        ,A.TotalPriceAdjustment
        ,@CreatedBy
    FROM @OrderProductAttributes A
    INNER JOIN @TempOrderDetails B ON A.ProductId = B.ProductID
    WHERE [OrderProductAttributeId] = 0;

    --Updating OrderProductAttributes
    UPDATE [dbo].[OrderProductAttributes]
    SET [OrderDetailId] = A.OrderDetailId
        ,[ProductId] = A.ProductId
        ,[AttributeId] = A.AttributeId
        ,[Product_ProductAttribute_MappingId] = A.Product_ProductAttribute_MappingId
        ,[ProductAttributeValueId] = A.ProductAttributeValueId
        ,[AttributeType] = A.AttributeType
        ,[AttributeName] = A.AttributeName
        ,[Name] = A.Name
        ,[PriceAdjustment] = A.PriceAdjustment
        ,[IsSubscription] = A.IsSubscription
        ,[Quantity] = A.Quantity
        ,[CustomerEntersQty] = A.CustomerEntersQty
        ,[TotalPriceAdjustment] = A.TotalPriceAdjustment
        ,[UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
    FROM @OrderProductAttributes A
    INNER JOIN OrderProductAttributes B ON A.OrderProductAttributeId = B.Id
    WHERE A.OrderDetailId IN (
            SELECT OrderDetailId
            FROM @OrderDetails
            WHERE UpdateType = 1
            );

    --Insert Into [dbo].[OrderDetailPromotions]
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderDetailPromotions] (
        [OrderDetailId]
        ,[ProductId]
        ,[PromotionId]
        ,[UniquePromotionId]
        ,[PromotionTypeId]
        ,[PromotionPrice]
        ,[ClassificationLevel]
        )
    SELECT ODP.OrderDetailId
        ,ODP.ProductId
        ,ODP.PromotionId
        ,ODP.UniquePromotionId
        ,ODP.PromotionTypeId
        ,ODP.PromotionPrice
        ,ODP.[ClassificationLevel]
    FROM @OrderDetailPromotions ODP
    INNER JOIN @OrderDetails A ON ODP.OrderDetailId = A.OrderDetailId
        AND UpdateType <> 2;-- If order detail will not in removed status.

    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM OrderDetails
            WHERE OrderDetails.OrderId = @OrderID
            ) -- We have an empty shopping cart
    BEGIN
        DELETE
        FROM Orders
        WHERE OrderId = @OrderID;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- If shopping cart is not empty, add order promotion.
        --Insert Into [dbo].[OrderPromotions]
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderPromotions] (
            [OrderId]
            ,[PromotionId]
            ,[PromotionTypeId]
            ,[UniquePromotionId]
            ,[PromotionCode]
            ,[PromotionAmt]
            )
        SELECT OP.OrderID
            ,OP.PromotionId
            ,OP.PromotionTypeId
            ,OP.UniquePromotionId
            ,OP.PromotionCode
            ,OP.PromotionAmt
        FROM @OrderPromotions OP
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION ShopCT_TRAN;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ShopCT_TRAN;

    SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,@ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();

    RAISERROR (
            @ErrMsg
            ,@ErrSeverity
            ,1
            )
END CATCH;
```

END
GO

Any kind of help will be appreciable.I have tried to put the second select stament out of if condition and try catch block. in that case it was working. or I can insert with separate query

Comment: what error you got

Comment: Is it throwing some error? or it just completes execution without error?

Comment: `I have tried to put the second select stament out of if condition ` - where is this `IF`?

Comment: How many records does `SELECT OrderPhaseId FROM OrderPhase WHERE OrderPhase = 'Shopping Carts'` return?  If it's more then 1 you could add a TOP 1.

Comment: It selects only one record

Comment: @pratik bhavsar,@Udhay Tisus - It does not show any error. it executes without errror

Comment: @Ivan Starostin - below is the condition.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE OrderId = @OrderID)

Comment: @Ramesh Try running select statement for the three parameters/variables you are using for the insert statement. As you mentioned there is also a not exists condition you are using with the statement, it will be helpful if you post that as well.

Comment: How are you checking that it does not insert anything? By some output value or by running `select` with new `orderid`? Where are you executing this script from: SSMS or your client-server application? Do you have transactions in this script? Also try placing schema name (`dbo`) before second table - this is a good practice and may avoid some issues with user's default schema different from dbo.

Comment: @IvanStarostin,@Pratik, I have edit the question and place the whole query.

Comment: Like @LukStorms mentioned, there is another problem in your code. In the "DECLARE OPhaseId INT..." section you assign a result set to a single value variable. Even if your query will, may be, return a single row, it is still a result set not a single value. This could be the reason your insert fails.

Comment: @TSungur It's probably more because of what Ivan described in his answer.  Originally Ramesh hadn't included the complete code, so it was without those deletes.  If one first inserts something then deletes it, there won't be an error, yet nothing will be added.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @OrderId = CONVERT(INT, SCOPE_IDENTITY());
...
--Deleting from OrderPromotion
    DELETE
    FROM [dbo].[OrderPromotions]
    WHERE [OrderId] = @OrderID;-- Removing exist Order Promotion for current order
```

Everything works properly. My guess is that you think that `@OrderID` here has the old, original value whereas it is already changed to new id.

To fix that rewrite this line to (and you don't really need explicit convertion here):

```
SET @NewOrderId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and use `@NewOrderId` for inserts and `@OrderID` for deletions.

Note, you should check whether there is an open transaction before rolling back inside CATCH block. Docs recommend to do this by checking [XACT_STATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) value

Comment: I agree. Changing the behavior around `@OrderID` and/or introducing a `@NewOrderId` variable will fix a lot of other issues here. But I think it will have no effect on the behavior of that second INSERT query (for the order details). So - despite the usefulness of your answer - I think it does not answer the OP's base question...

Answer (score 0):

The second INSERT query inserts data from table-parameter `@OrderDetails` into table `[dbo].[OrderDetails]`.

My first suggestion would be to check the results of the SELECT-query for that insert operation. Perhaps `@OrderDetails` is empty... Or `@OrderDetails` does not contain any records `WHERE [OrderDetailId] = 0 AND [UpdateType] = 0`...